I submitted wrong Schengen visa application form 1 question
I mistakenly answered no in form to a question stating if I had biometrics before I had I even had the Schengen visa this mistake was purely unintentional but I am worried I will declared as a fraud even though I told the consultant there that I had biometric before he was unable to find it and I had my biometrics before I attached my visa along with my application will my application will be rejected

I don't think they will label you as a fraudster because of that, but in addition to (maybe) needlessly having to go in to have biometrics recorded, such a lack of attention might make them check everything else a little harder. But if you answered everything else truthfully and generally fulfil the criteria for getting a visa, I don't think (but I'm neither a visa official) that will make them reject your application.
